# Nothing executes AFTER for-loops, only before

Tags: for-loop, p5.js

I have been having this issue with p5js on multiple coding projects. Once I have two or more for-loops (they are not nested) in the sketch, nothing will execute AFTER the loop.

I worked around this issue in previous sketches by changing around the order and putting the for-loops last.
However, for my current sketch, I need a for-loop to build on information about arrays in the previous loop. I've even tried adding a simple shape after the loop and before. And the shape will only execute and render on the sketch when it is included BEFORE.

The code for my sketch is quite long but if it will be useful to include it I can.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of this behavior. Strip out all unnecessary parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If the code after a loop is never executed it might mean that your loop never finishes.

I'd recommend using `console.log()` to debug instead of drawing shapes. This way you can also debug inside the for loop and see if it works correctly.

For example, you can do something like this

```
console.log("Before loop");

for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  console.log(`Inside loop. Iteration ${i}`);
}

console.log("After loop");
```

This code will print

```
Before loop
Inside loop. Iteration 0
Inside loop. Iteration 1
Inside loop. Iteration 2
Inside loop. Iteration 3
Inside loop. Iteration 4
After loop
```

As you can see, it's very easy with this code to see that the log before the loop is executed, that the loop executes 5 times and finally the log after the loop is executed.

Put something like this in your code and it will help looking where the code fails.